# The displacement of a body executing Simple harmonic motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, waves, experimental-physics

> The displacement of a body executing Simple harmonic motion is given by $x= A\sin(2πt + π/3)$. The first time from t=0 when velocity is maximum is
>
> Options :$ 1/12 s , 1/6 s, 1/3s , 1/2s$

So I tried the question and I got answer 1/3 but the correct answer is 1/12 s .I am confused. Can someone tell which answer is correct from above mentioned options.

Comment: Could you please outline the steps you followed? I am sure you are maximizing $v$ by setting $dv/dt=0$ and $d^2v/dt^2<0$.

Comment: No, I tried to find w(omega) and then time period by putting x=0

Comment: i think it should be 1/3

Comment: Alternative to the below answer, you could also derive an expression for $v$ which is proportional to $\cos x$ and then set $\cos x = \pm 1$, the sign depending on sign of $A$.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Max speed occurs at zero displacement, which for $A\sin{x}=0$ means $x=0$ or $x=\pi$. Given the phase, term: choose $\pi$--it's the 1st crossing after $t=0$:

$$ 2\pi t+ \pi/3 = \pi$$

$$ 2t = 2/3 $$

$$ t = 1/3 $$.